# How can I find similar float values from diferent dataframes rows considering a tolerance range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, one of them generated by a system (DF A, correct values) and the other is generated manually by users (DF B, some of the values are not correct). They have some columns in common which must have the same OR SIMILAR row values, so I need to find the differences in order to correct DF B.

My problem is I can't figure out how to match SIMILAR values from the dataframes. A tolerance of +-1.5 is desirable. The values could be or not in the same row index, and the size of the dataframes is always different.

For exact row values I used `merge()`, but I understand conditions can't be used in this method. I also tried with `isin()` `(DFA.isin({'col2':DFB['col2'],'col3':DFA['col3']}).all(1))` but I also understand it only works for exact values too, as I can't write a tolerance range in a dictionary `{'col2':DFB['col2']+-1.5}`.

```
          DFA                         DFB
   col1   col2    col3           col2   col3    D
0  51.1   52.2    12.0       0   51.5   12.0    ad
1  54.0   11.0   452.0       1   45.0   52.5   asd
2  64.3   10.0    46.0       2    1.0   23.0   dws
3   8.0   46.0    52.0
```

The result (considering columns `'col2'` and `'col3'` with a tolerance +-1.5) should be a match of rows:

```
0 DFA --> 0 DFB
3 DFA --> 1 DFB
```

Comment: Have you searched for "pandas merge dataframe tolerance"? Quite a few results come up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge efficiently two dataframes with a tolerance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790335/how-to-merge-efficiently-two-dataframes-with-a-tolerance-in-python)

Comment: @LukasKaspras thanks for your answer, I checked the link. I would prefer no iterations.